# Is there any way to use a WHERE clause with the combination of two VARCHAR fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a new PHP page and I have a variable which consists out of the addition of two fields of my MySQL database. I would like to find which row corresponds to the variable, which consists of a combination of two fields.

I was unable to find any answers online, and when I did, none of them seem to work.

Database example:

```
 ID | Name 1  | Name 2
----+---------+--------
 1  | john 1  | doe
 2  | jane    | doe
 3  | john    | doe
 4  | john    | doe 1
```

My variable which I ought to match to a row is `$var = "john doe 1";`, and splitting my variable is not an option.

I expect the output of said SQL statement to be the row with `ID = 4`.

EDIT: I do not believe this to be a duplicate. I'm not having any problems with the CONCAT clause itself, I was consulting about which clause to use and how to use it, not how to fix my current one.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
where concat(name1, ' ', name2) = 'john doe 1'
```

Note:  It is tempting to write:

```
where concat(name1, ' ', name2) = '$var'
```

However, you should learn to use parameters when passing constant values into a query.

Comment: 3 reasons for downvote: 1. You answered a question which is a duplicate. 2. You used `concat` instead of `CONCAT_WS`. 3. You didn't show how to use prepared statements and left that part very unclear.